# Need help for my homework, wordy math problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Given a manufacturing line of 4 phases with:

Phase 1 (5s) -> Phase 2 (10s) -> Phase 3 (8s) -> Phase 4 (7s) -> finished

In each phase, there can only be 1 product under working ( maximum capacity of 1). A product must follow this process. Assuming there is no failure in the manufacturing line, calculate the total number of output after time T= 100s and T= n (second)

My attempt: i tried to calculate the interval after the first product is finished which is 7 second. It seems wrong to me and i dont know whether there is better approach

Comment: Let me know if my question is ambiguous. Thanks!

Comment: it's better to mention what you tried as well.

Comment: @zaira I have updated my attempt

Comment: The way I read this is that a product is manufactured by going through all four phases of production, so the time it takes to manufacture a product would be the sum of the times for each phase.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes but different products can be worked on simultaneously in different phases

Comment: @N.F.Taussig for example product 1 2 3 can all be on the line at the same time

Comment: Three reactions: (1) Please clarify: "i tried to calculate the interval after the first product is finished which is 7 second".  What interval are you referring to? (2) If I understand correctly, the limiting factor is whether one of the phases represents a *bottleneck*.  Which phase takes the longest?  Given the specified times for each phase, is there any way to *avoid* the delay caused by the bottleneck? (3) You have to consider **start-up** costs - for example, creating a single product only will require 30 seconds.

Comment: @user2661923 the interval after the first 30s is 7s if i did not miscalculate

Comment: @user2661923  the bottle neck is from phase 2 which take up 10s

Comment: Right re identifying bottleneck.  Re the interval after the first 30s is 7s, where is this coming from - it's not specified in the problem - so please explain how you computed a 7s *interval*?

Comment: @user2661923 i got the interval because in step 4 it took 7s to finish a product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you start the process with nothing in the pipeline, the first item is completed in $30$ seconds; and then every $10$ seconds thereafter, another item is completed.

$\begin{array}{cc|c|c|c|c}
 &\rm{phase}&1&2&3&4\\
\rm{item}&&&\\
 1&&0-5&5-15&15-23&23-30\\
2&&5-10&15-25&25-33&33-40\\
3&&10-15&25-35&35-43&43-50\\
4&&15-20&35-45&45-53&53-60\\
\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&
\end{array}$

Comment: Thx, this is amazing